# firebase test lab login unable to move forward after login screen

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-test-lab

In Firebase Test Lab after providing id for login screen for automatic login, The video shows that it is not able to enter password field successfully.

Is it because password field is hidden and is not displayed on screen?

Also Video shows test went back and forth many times , entering correct details and than clearing it in other login fields.

I have three login fields ORGKey , USer ID and password , it successfully entered the two but not password.

I checked that password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A Robo test simulates what a user might do when using the app.  How would a user enter a password in an invisible or hidden input field?

Your EditText fields need to actually be visible and enabled in order for Robo to interact with them.